# Zsh script how to concatanate array elements with string

Tags: shell-script, zsh, string, array

I have written a `zsh` script to automize an analysis in high energy physics and now I would like to use an element of the one of the defined array some string and another element of some another array in a command that is passed to one of the string. My code follows below:

```
bkgarr=(TopJets BosonJets DiBoson TTbar)
sigarr=(NM1 NM2 NM3 Scenario4 Scenario6)
puarr=(50PU 140PU)
lumarr=(30 300 3000)

echo Please type 1 for 50PU samples and 2 for 140PU samples
read PU
if [[ $PU -ne 1 && $PU -ne 2 ]] ; then
    echo You have to enter 1 or 2
    return 1
fi

echo Please type 1 for 300fb-1 and 2 for 3000fb-1
read lum

if [[ $lum -ne 1 && $lum -ne 2 ]] ; then
    echo You have to enter 1 or 2
    return 1
fi

if [ $PU = 1 ]; then
    let "lum = $lum + 1"
    #echo $lum
fi

root -l << EOF
.L readerSummerStd.C+
.q
EOF

ex NEWrunReader.py  <<EOEX
  :43s/Lumi.*/Lumi=$lumarr[lum]/
  :x
EOEX

echo Press any key to proceed or Ctrl+C to abort!
read
for index in $bkgarr
do
    screen -dmS $index"_"$lumarr[lum]
    #screen -S $index -p 0 -X stuff "$(typeset -p bkgarr)"$'\r'
    screen -S $index"_"$lumarr[lum] -p 0 -X stuff "./NEWrunReader.py SummerStd $puarr[PU]_$index >& $index"_"$lumarr[lum].txt &"$'\r'
done
for sigind in $sigarr
do
    screen -dmS $sigin"_"$lumarr[lum]
    #screen -S $sigind -p 0 -X stuff "$(typeset -p bkgarr)"$'\r'
    screen -S $sigin"_"$lumarr[lum] -p 0 -X stuff "./NEWrunReader.py SummerStd $puarr[PU]_$sigind >& $sigind"_"$lumarr[lum].txt &"$'\r'
done
return 0
```

I thought the following code snippets would do, but they failed:

```
$index+"_"+$lumarr[lum]
$index"_"$lumarr[lum]
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me with this.

Comment: Change `$lumarr[lum]` to `${lumarr[$lum]}` and retry.

Comment: Are you sure your script is being interpreted by `zsh`. `screen -S $sigin"_"$lumarr[lum]` would work in `zsh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
"${index}_${lumarr[lum]}"
```

Generally:

1. Interpolate all variables using `${...}` notation.
2. Unless you expressly want to use word-splitting, always enclose variable interpolations in double-quoted strings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am at a bit of lost with the technical terms `interpolate` and `word-splitting`.

Comment: Interpolation means replacing `$index` with `TopJets`. Word splitting means replacing the single word `$bkgarr` with the 4 words `TopJets BosonJets DiBoson TTbar` instead of the single word `"TopJets BosonJets DiBoson TTbar"`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. I would like to use word-splitting always so should I enclose the elements of the array in double quotes? I am asking this because my second for loop does not work after the modification and five screen is terminating messages are displayed in stdout after some delay.

Comment: If you want word-splitting, don't use double-quotes. The second for loop has a typo of `sigin` for `sigind`; is that it?

Comment: I think it was some sort of typo introduced using search and replace function of the text editor. It works fine now, but I am not sure of the exact problem I just copied the above for loop which was working fine.

Comment: word splitting upon parameter expansion doesn't apply to `zsh` except when emulating other shells (probably the OP is not using zsh though).